# How to combine both array and insert into database php

Tags: php

if only one array is there for example

```
$values = array(x, y, z);
```

i am adding them into database like this

```
    foreach ($values as $value)
    {
        $insertFunction = addValues($value);
    }
```

my arrays:

```
$array1 = Array ( 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 );

$array2 = Array ( fb1, or1, fb2, or2, fb3, or3, fb4, or4, fb5, or5 );
```

But i want both array to combine and insert them into database.
How can i do this please help me

Updated:

When i am printing the POST values i am getting out put like this

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 [4] => 1 [5] => 2 [6] => 1 [7] => 2 [8] => 1 [9] => 2 )

Array ( [0] => fb1 [1] => or1 [2] => fb2 [3] => or2 [4] => fb3 [5] => or3 [6] => fb4 [7] => or4 [8] => fb5 [9] => or5 )
```

when i tried with array_merge my out put is like this

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 [4] => 1 [5] => 2 [6] => 1 [7] => 2 [8] => 1 [9] => 2 [10] => fb1 [11] => or1 [12] => fb2 [13] => or2 [14] => fb3 [15] => or3 [16] => fb4 [17] => or4 [18] => fb5 [19] => or5 )
```

How to insert them in separate columns in a table $array1 and $array2

my database table is like this

1.id 
2.username
3.network_id

id is primary key
network_id values coming in array1
username values coming in array2

Comment: What in the world? Is one array keys, the other values? Are they both values? What is the addValues function doing?

Comment: Just combine them first to a third array the way you want and then use the same code to insert it into database. What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: i have to insert them in separate column in a table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**:

After you mentioned seperated columns I think I understand what you're looking for:
I'm assuming that array1 and array2 are in the same size.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++)
{

  $array2[$i] = (int)$array2[$i]; //"validating" the username (an integer)
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO yourTableName (`username`,`network_id`) VALUES('".$array2[$i]."','".$array1[$i]."')");
}
```

Result:

> tblName:
>
> username:   1  2 1 ...
>
> network_id:  fb1 or1 fb2 ...

Is that what you were looking for?

**Ignore** this and merging:

```
    $combined = array_merge($array1 , $array2);

   //$combined = Array ( 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2,fb1, or1, fb2, or2, fb3, or3, fb4, or4, fb5, or5 );
```

Comment: How to insert them in separate columns in a table $array1 and $array2

Comment: I related to your question before you've updated it.
Can you be more specific? It will help if you provide the `DB tables scheme` and an example.

Comment: can i validate them? if yes, please tell me how can i do it.

Comment: what do you mean when you say 'validate'?

Comment: i mean normal validation. i want to validate if any extra spaces are there and given format is correct or not.

Comment: "normal validation" ? please be more specific.
About the usernames , validating only if those are numbers?
About the networks_id , checking if there are 2 letters and 1 digit?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_merge()](http://php.net/array_merge), function to merge multiple array into one.

```
$arrays = array_merge($array1 , $array2);
foreach ($arrays as $value)
{
    $insertFunction = addValues($value);
}
```

Comment: How to insert them in separate columns in a table $array1 and $array2

Answer (score 0):

If you want associate an element from array a to an element from array b, you have to use array_combine() function.

```
$arrays = array_combine($array1,$array2);
foreach ($array as $aValue)
{
    $insertFunction = addValues($aValue);
}
```